# Need to replace all the strings staring with 0 (except having / and .) in a text file with same string in double quotes

Tags: awk

```
    awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^0[a-z,0-9][a-z,0-9]/){print $i}}}' test1 > test3

 doWork()

 { rm /tmp/test1 && awk '{sub(/'$I'/, "\"'$I'\"", $0); print}' >test1;} < test1

 for I in `cat /tmp/test3`
 do doWork;
 done;
```

Input text file:

> /tmp # cat test1 1234      012345
>   0.000 01/02/03 01234 05554567 0qwertyu 0099 0000           000012
>   1800.000000 099000 0123456789

Current Output:

> 1234      ""01234"5"
>   0.000 01/02/03 "01234" "05554567" "0qwertyu" "0099" "0000"           "000012"
>   1800."0000"00 "099000" ""01234"5"6789

Expected output:

> 1234      "012345"
>   0.000 01/02/03 "01234" "05554567" "0qwertyu" 0099 "0000"           "000012"
>   1800.000000 "099000" "0123456789"

Comment: why isnt `0099` wrapped with quotes?

Comment: Yes 0099 also should be quoted. I forgot by mistake.

Comment: @AnilKumar please edit the question instead of comment.. and is the input multiple line or single line? I don't see why the edit by Dinidu was approved

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v dq='"' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^0/ && $i!~/[./]/) $i=dq $i dq} 1' file
1234 "012345"
0.000
01/02/03
"01234"
"05554567"
"0qwertyu"
"0099"
"0000" "000012"
1800.000000
"099000"
"0123456789"
```

- this won't preserve the input spacing though, if input is `tab` separated, set FS/OFS accordingly.. `awk -v dq='"' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^0/ && $i!~/[./]/) $i=dq $i dq} 1'`
- `-v dq='"'` variable to store a double quote
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` iterate over all input fields
- `if($i~/^0/ && $i!~/[./]/)` if any field starts with `0` and doesn't have `.` or `/`

  - `$i=dq $i dq` surround that field with double quotes
- `1` print the input record, including any changes made to the fields

To preserve spacing

```
$ perl -lpe 's#(^|\h)\K0[^./\h]+(?=\h|$)#"$&"#g' file
1234    "012345"
0.000
01/02/03
"01234"
"05554567"
"0qwertyu"
"0099"
"0000"  "000012"
1800.000000
"099000"
"0123456789"
```

Comment: Both the command you have given working perfectly but how to merge the effect of both command at same time as 1st command putting the quotes only and 2nd command preserving the spacing only.

Comment: see edit, the perl command preserves space as well as adds quotes

Comment: you really should put all these details and explain in the question, not in comments.. you can see for yourself that formatting cannot be conveyed in comments... and clearly explain your requirements, if your current sample is not enough to explain the problem then change it

Comment: The Perl command is working fine in linux on bash shell but it is not ok on /sbin/sh shell for root in HP UX (No Double quotes)                                                                           #echo $SHELL                                                                                                /sbin/sh                                                                                                   /tmp # perl -lpe 's#(^|\h)\K0[^./\h]+(?=\h|$)#"$&"#g' test1
1234      012345
0.000
01/02/03
01234
05554567
0qwertyu
0099
0000           000012
1800.000000
099000
0123456789

Answer (score 0):

> Yes 0099 also should be quoted. I forgot by mistake.

```
$ awk -v q='"' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)if($i ~/^0[[:alnum:]][^.\/]/)$i=q $i q}1' infile
1234 "012345"
0.000
01/02/03
"01234"
"05554567"
"0qwertyu"
"0099"
"0000" "000012"
1800.000000
"099000"
"0123456789"
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
1234      012345
0.000
01/02/03
01234
05554567
0qwertyu
0099
0000           000012
1800.000000
099000
0123456789
```

Explanation:

`/^0[[:alnum:]][^.\/]/`

- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- `0` matches the character 0 literally
- Match a single character present in the list below `[[:alnum:]]`
  `[:alnum:]` matches a alphanumeric character `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^.\/]`
  `.` matches the character . literally 
  `\/` matches the character / literally

Comment: The command you have given is working fine but the output does not preserve the spacing between string in line 1 and line 8 of input. The spacing of tab in the input is getting converted into single character space in the output.

Comment: add `-v OFS="\t"` becomes `awk -v q='"' -v OFS="\t"`