# add a " once string matched using sed in multiple lines

Tags: bash, sed

while i am trying to replace a string using below command, all the strings are replaced which is having a 0.But, I need to replace only a string starting with 0 and combination of alpha numeric.Please help to exclude the others.Please find the sed command below what i used.

```
sed -r 's:((0\w+)):"&":g'  test >test.log
```

input file:   test

```
0INTEL  GC  P   0servername     0.000       0I30019     12/02/15
0INTEL  GC  P   0servername     0.000       0I30019     12/02/15
```

Expected output:  test.log

```
"0INTEL"    GC  P   "0servername"   0.000       I30019      12/02/15
"0INTEL"    GC  P   "0servername"   0.000       I30019      12/02/15
```

Actual output:

```
"0INTEL"    GC  P   "0servername"   0."000"     I30019      12/"02"/15
"0INTEL"    GC  P   "0servername"   0."000"     I30019      12/"02"/15
```

Comment: looks like question asked differently by creating new account.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298909/need-to-replace-all-the-strings-staring-with-0-except-having-and-in-a-text still not sure what was the issue with answers given in that question

Comment: Hello sundeep,  Thanks for checking, simple I need to exclude date and special character which is starting with zero.  The same I have given a actual output which I got while I used the above command... I hope not you can able to understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `awk`. For all fields, if field matches pattern, add quotes. Finally print the line (`1` means the default action which is to print line)

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^0[A-Za-z0-9]*$/) $i="\""$i"\"" } 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "expected output" seems to have an error. The leading 0s from "0I30019" have been removed for some reason. Otherwise, what you need is something like this:

```
sed -r 's/((0[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*))/"&"/g' text
```

Based on your example, the first character after the leading 0 should be an alphabet, but the word can contain numeric chars after that. The regex reflects that requirement. The output from this:

```
"0INTEL" GC P "0servername" 0.000 "0I30019" 12/02/15 "0INTEL" GC P "0servername" 0.000 "0I30019" 12/02/15
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing, as per your suggest i updated the file.

Answer (score -1):

Just another awk proposal.

```
awk '{sub(/0INTEL/,"\0420INTEL\042")sub(/0servername/,"\0420servername\042")}1' file

"0INTEL"  GC  P   "0servername"     0.000       0I30019     12/02/15
"0INTEL"  GC  P   "0servername"     0.000       0I30019     12/02/15
```

Comment: thank you for your Sharing commands,  the above one is example..  The main issue is strings(input) are dynamic, not static..  But this will work as per the static input...